# Add svnserve to Mac OSX Lion firewall

Tags: macos, firewall, svnserve

Can somebody please explain how to add svnserve (or any other application that doesn't have a UI) to the Mac OSX Lion application firewall ? The UI doesn't let you select hidden folders like /usr/bin

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out? I've been trying to work through http://krypted.com/tag/socketfilterfw/ but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I did get it working, but it was so long ago that I can't remember which article it was I found that worked. This one looks familiar, but I'm not 100% sure: http://zennaware.com/cornerstone/helpbook/pages/appendix/launchd.html